# Area calculation doesn't make sense: smaller raster has higher area

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, area

I'm comparing two rasters calculating their area. One of them is noticeably (see image below) larger than the other on the map. But when calculating the area, the one that looks smaller gives a larger area. I even tried to reproject both rasters, but I got the same pattern.

What am I missing?

```js
// a sample area
var SP = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1').filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Sao Paulo'));

// global croplands raster
var image = ee.ImageCollection('users/potapovpeter/Global_cropland_2019').mosaic();
var mask = image.gt(0);
var crops = image.updateMask(mask);
crops = crops.clip(SP);

var vizParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette:['black','red']
};


Map.setCenter(-49.008, -21.507, 7); 
Map.addLayer(crops,vizParams,  'Cropland UMD');

Map.addLayer(SP,{},'Limites SP', false);

// global cropland data area in hectares. It should be larger than the other:
var croplands = crops.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e4).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: SP,
  scale: 30,
  bestEffort: true
});

print('global cropland area (UMD)', croplands);


// Brazilian LULC
var asset = ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_integration_v1');

var palettes = require('users/mapbiomas/modules:Palettes.js');
var vis = {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 45,
    'palette': palettes.get('classification6')
};


// selection specific years
var mapbiomas_2019 = asset.select('classification_2019');
var mapbiomas_2018 = asset.select('classification_2018');
var mapbiomas_2017 = asset.select('classification_2017');
var mapbiomas_2016 = asset.select('classification_2016');

// selection of land use classes
var mapbiomas_2019_Crops = asset.select('classification_2019').remap([39,20,40],[1,1,1]);
var mapbiomas_2018_Crops = asset.select('classification_2018').remap([39,20,40],[1,1,1]);
var mapbiomas_2017_Crops = asset.select('classification_2017').remap([39,20,40],[1,1,1]);
var mapbiomas_2016_Crops = asset.select('classification_2016').remap([39,20,40],[1,1,1]);

// join different years
var mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops = mapbiomas_2019_Crops.add(mapbiomas_2018_Crops).add(mapbiomas_2017_Crops).add(mapbiomas_2016_Crops);
mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops = mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops.selfMask();
mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops = mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops.clip(SP);

Map.addLayer(mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops,{},'mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops');

// calculate mapbiomas area in hectares. It should be smaller then the previous one
var mapbiomas_area = mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e4).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: SP,
  scale: 30,
  bestEffort: true
});

print('cropland area (MapBiomas)', mapbiomas_area);

// It's both in 4326 projection
print('projection mapbiomas', mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops.projection());
print('projection umd', crops.projection());

// checking if projection is the issue
// reproject to EPSG 5880 (meters)

var mapbiomas_reprojected = mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops
    .reproject('EPSG:5880', null, 30);

var umd_reprojected = crops
    .reproject('EPSG:5880', null, 30);


// calculating reprojected area
var mapbiomas_reprojected_area = mapbiomas_reprojected.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e4).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: SP,
  scale: 30,
  bestEffort: true
});

var umd_reprojected_area = umd_reprojected.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e4).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: SP,
  scale: 30,
  bestEffort: true
});

// no, it's not projection issu. Why then?
print('reprojected area in hectares (MapBiomas)', mapbiomas_reprojected_area);
print('reprojected area in hectares (UMD)', umd_reprojected_area);
```

As you can see in the image below, black (mapbiomas) is obviously smaller than red (UMD) and it largely overlaps red but calculated areas are showing the oopposite. I'm 100% sure something is not right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why, but figured it out. The issue is the way I'm "merging" the 4 crop rasters from Mapbiomas of different years. As they all are coded as 1, I was summing them up to get a final raster and then masking the resulting raster with values different from 4 as I'm looking for "stable" crops.

```js
var mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops = mapbiomas_2019_Crops
    .add(mapbiomas_2018_Crops)
    .add(mapbiomas_2017_Crops)
    .add(mapbiomas_2016_Crops);

mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops = mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops.selfMask();
```

Not sure why, but this approach results in a wrong area calculation in the end. Using boolean operators on rasters, instead of summing them up, results in the right area calculation.

```js
var mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops = mapbiomas_2019_Crops
                                .and(mapbiomas_2018_Crops)
                                .and(mapbiomas_2017_Crops)
                                .and(mapbiomas_2016_Crops);

mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops = mapbiomas_2016_2019_crops.selfMask();
```

wrong approach: 23,907,583 ha
right approach: 5,976,895 ha

As I said, I don't know why. But it works.

Comment: The area would be wrong because you're multiplying the area by the image values that are 4. You can use `.mask().multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())` to compute the unmasked area and ignore the pixel values.